# Is it possible to restart your app programmatically

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, restart

I'm looking for a way to reboot my app after an in app purchase has been made. Once the user upgrades I need the ads to go away and to basically reload the app from scratch so all the new functionality will be added the next time the app loads.  I'm thinking the easiest way is going to be to exit the app then automatically restart the app but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Can you provide more specifics relating to the context of this app?

Comment: Apple would reject this, they specifically say not to do it in the HIG. Not sure why you don't think you can just update the state in your app to remove the ads... maybe ask those related programming questions for help?

Comment: I can handle the removing the ads but everything is set up to display the correct view configuration on app launch so it was basically an easy solution.  I just thought I'd see if this was a possibility.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Use NSNotification to perform the required. Trigger the notification when you get the purchase confirmation and add in observer. Code the logic to remove adds in the observer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Instead allow your app to alter itself when something has been purchased.  Call a method on the objects that need to have their content changed so they can be notified of the state change and alter their own internals to conform.

Sometimes if it seems there is no way to do what you want, then there is a better way.

Comment: +1, if you need to reboot your app to make this change, there's something wrong with its design.

Comment: I basically agree. I ended up in this question because i offer the user a possibility to change the applications language setting. changes to the standardUserDefaults require a restart, don't they?

Comment: No, they do not.  Anytime you write to standard defaults, whatever you write is immediately available for reading afterward.  Not restart required.

Comment: I'm with @samsam my app allows for language change through the settings. But the only way to load a different language is when the app is loaded (in main.c) so a "cold restart" would be the ideal.